# Why shell always execute vim in /usr/bin rather than vim in /opt/homebrew/bin?

Tags: macos, shell, vim, path

I don't want to use the vim bundled on the macOS, so I download new vim using homebrew.
My environment variable PATH is set as follows:
`/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. The vim downloaded using brew in in **/opt/homebrew/bin**, and vim bundled with macOS is in **/usr/bin**. However, when I input vim on the shell, it always execute /usr/bin/vim(i.e. the vim bundled with macOS).

Does anyone know how to solve this or what is the reason for this circumstance? Very appreciate any help.

[image: the situation when I execute vim and tmux in shell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! I know why is that. After installing new vim using brew, we need to reboot the terminal. I know this because I I accidentally shut down the terminal, then I open the terminal and find the vim in /opt/homebrew/bin can be executed when I input vim in the shell.

For beginners, this is a difficult problem to find the reason. I solved this problem myself, hoping to help people who encounter the same problem

Comment: Just to add to your answer, you don't actually have to restart your terminal, you can also use `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` for bash and zsh respectively to refresh the environmental variables

Comment: Note that simply resourcing `.zshrc` may not be sufficient, as shells cache the results of previous path lookups. Restarting the shell starts an instance with an empty cache, while simply updating the value of `PATH` will require invalidating or updating the cache as well. (Use the `hash` command in either `bash` or `zsh` to view and/or manipulate the cache, but the usage differs between the two shells; consult the man page for details.)